# Evaluate the limit: $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xy+yz^2+xz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^4}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Could someone give me a hint? I would like to continue to attempt it. The limit to evaluate that I would like a hint on is:

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xy+yz^2+xz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^4}$$

Comment: You can use [spherical coordinate approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417204/find-limits-of-a-function-with-several-variables/417273#417273).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Along the curve $x=y=z^2$, the function is identically $1$.
2. Along the line $y=z=0$, the function is identically $0$.
3. Along the line $x=y, z=0$, the function is identically $\frac 12$.
4. Along the line $x=2y, z=0$, the function is identically $\frac 25$.

Comment: And therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: very nice hint  +1